# PDOException: Could not find driver (SQL: select * from `posts`)

Tags: laravel

I am working on Laravel 8 project, I ran migrations and made models, resource controller, routes and views. After running project with routing, "could not find driver" error was appeared. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like PDO is not installed on server. What does phpinfo show?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a missing dependency. run these commands

```
composer update
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

second solution:  Edit your php.ini .Find and uncomment the following line
(remove the ; character)

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so //uncomment this line just remove ;
```

Comment: This solution work for me. Tnx bro.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your database driver is missing.

What you can do is:
First install the driver

For ubuntu and mysql database.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.x-mysql
```

*Minimum is php7.3 as that is the minimum requirement for laravel 8.*

You also can search for other database systems.
To search for available driver in your machine/server:

```
sudo apt-cache search drivername
```

Then run the command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

If your php version is correct then

Need to open php.ini file.
uncomment `extension=pdo_mysql.so;` by removing the # in the beginning

Then, restart your Apache server. For more information, please read the documentation.

Comment: How can I restart Apache server on windows 10?